# Cannot create a QWidget without QApplication

Tags: c++, qt

When i compile my qt project showed below error?

```
QWidget: Cannot create a QWidget without QApplication
```

What is the problem?

> Main.cpp

```
#include<QApplication>
#include"MainWindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need a `QApplication` to have a `QWidget`. Change `QGuiApplication` to `QApplication` and the code will run just fine.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "MainWindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

If you want to know "Why there are three main classes like QApplication, QGuiApplication and QCoreApplication", see [this](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/60203-QApplication-QGuiApplication-and-QCoreApplication). It says:

> QCoreApplication is the base class, QGuiApplication extends the base
> class with functionality related to handling windows and GUI stuff
> (non-widget related, e.g. OpenGL or QtQuick), QApplication extends
> QGuiApplication with functionality related to handling widgets.

Btw, isn't it the basic example available on Qt Creator? You need a book to learn Qt, and I suggest you to read "C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4 (2nd Edition)" from Jasmin Blanchette.

[image: Qt Book]

Comment: The crucial distinction between QGuiApplication and QApplication this book won't cover though, as it is about Qt 4, and QGuiApplication was introduced in Qt5.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I've mentioned the difference between QApplication, QGuiApplication and QCoreApplication from http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/60203. Do you know a good Qt5 book?

Answer (score 6):

You should change `QGuiApplication` to `QApplication` in your main.

From [QGuiApplication Class Description](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html):

> For QWidget based Qt applications, use QApplication instead, as it
>   provides some functionality needed for creating QWidget instances.